# Custom product option not added in quote (prog)

Tags: magento2, custom-options, quote

Hi I'm creating a quote manualy.

This quote contains a virtual product (so related to a configurable product).

My quote is submitted, but the options from the parent product is not added to the quote.

I've got this :

```
   $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
   $buyRequest->setData([
       'qty' => $qty,
       'super_attribute' => [
             58 => 328,
       ],
       'options' => [58 => 328,]
        ]);
       $quote->addProduct($product,$buyRequest);
```

This **[58 => 328,]** refers to the parent product. Is this why my product doesn't have any option when the quote is submitted ?

(58 is the custom option id and 328 is id of the selected value)

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that the $product refers to the configurable product.
2. super_attribute refers to the configurable options so make sure to pass the configurable attribute id => configurable option id instead of  58 => 328.
3. You forgot to pass the product_id.

Here is how it should look

```
$buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
   $buyRequest->setData([
       'qty' => $qty,
       'super_attribute' => [
             <configurable attribute id> => <configurable option id>,
       ],
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
       'options' => [58 => 328]
        ]);
    $quote->addProduct($product,$buyRequest);
```

Comment: So in my swatch I've seen this **option-label-ambiance-236-item-318**, configurable attribute id is 236 and option id is 318 ? 
PS : when the $product is the configurable product, the product is not added to quote anymore

Comment: Yes, it was this. You're my savior and master !!! BTW for the others, for **super_attribute**, if the field is a multiselect, don't forget to put the values in an array !

Comment: @MorganTartreau - it's great to hear! Can you please kudos me by accepting my answer?

Comment: Yes, it's done :)

Comment: Thanks so much!